# How do i get all the data in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I couldn't able to get all the data from this site, it's just giving me the same data multiple time.

I tried with custom xpath but it's giving me the data single data multiple times.

```
import time
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.spicejet.com/")

departureButton = 
browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT")

departureButton.click()
browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Kolkata").click()

arivalButton = browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTXT")
arivalButton.click()

browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Goa").click()

date_position = 
browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_mainContent_view_date1")
date_position.click()

search_date = "20-September 2019"
dep_date = search_date.split("-")

dep_month = dep_date[1]
dep_day = dep_date[0]

while browser.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-title").text !=  dep_month:
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[data-handler='next']").click()

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//table//a[text()='"+dep_day+"']").click()
time.sleep(1)
pax_selct = browser.find_element_by_id("divpaxinfo").click()
time.sleep(.2)
# adult number
for i in range(0, 1 - 1):
    adults = browser.find_element_by_id("hrefIncAdt")
    adults.click()
# child number
for i in range(0, 1):
    childrens = browser.find_element_by_id("hrefIncChd")
    childrens.click()
# infant number
for i in range(0, 1):
    infants = browser.find_element_by_id("hrefIncInf")
    infants.click()

donebttn = browser.find_element_by_id("btnclosepaxoption").click()

searchBtn = 
browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_mainContent_btn_FindFlights").click()

browser.switch_to.default_content()
flightarr = []
tbl_row = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("fare-row")
for item in tbl_row:
    if item.is_displayed():
        col = item
        flightinfo = {}
        flightNo = col.find_element_by_class_name("special").text
        depTime = col.find_element_by_class_name("departure-time").text
        trvlDuration = col.find_element_by_class_name("travel-duration").text
        arrv_time = col.find_element_by_class_name("hide-below-480").text
        price1 = item.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="availabilityTable0"]/tbody/tr/td[3]').text
        price2 = item.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="availabilityTable0"]/tbody/tr/td[4]').text
        price3 = item.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="availabilityTable0"]/tbody/tr/td[5]').text
        price4 = item.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="availabilityTable0"]/tbody/tr/td[6]').text


        flightinfo["flight_number"] = flightNo
        flightinfo["depart_time"] = depTime
        flightinfo["flight_duration"] = trvlDuration
        flightinfo["arrival_time"] = arrv_time
        flightinfo["i0"] = price1
        flightinfo["i1"] = price2
        flightinfo["i2"] = price3
        flightinfo["i3"] = price4

    flightarr.append(flightinfo)

print(flightarr)
time.sleep(2)
# browser.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to limit the scope in the for loop to the current item by adding `.` in the xpath. 
Here is the script that you should use.

```
for item in tbl_row:
    if item.is_displayed():
        col = item
        flightinfo = {}
        flightNo = col.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='special']").text
        depTime = col.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='departure-time']").text
        trvlDuration = col.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='travel-duration']").text 
        arrv_time = col.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='hide-below-480']").text
        price1 = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="availabilityTable0"]/tbody/tr/td[3]').text
        price2 = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="availabilityTable0"]/tbody/tr/td[4]').text
        price3 = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="availabilityTable0"]/tbody/tr/td[5]').text
        price4 = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="availabilityTable0"]/tbody/tr/td[6]').text


        flightinfo["flight_number"] = flightNo
        flightinfo["depart_time"] = depTime
        flightinfo["flight_duration"] = trvlDuration
        flightinfo["arrival_time"] = arrv_time
        flightinfo["i0"] = price1
        flightinfo["i1"] = price2
        flightinfo["i2"] = price3
        flightinfo["i3"] = price4

    flightarr.append(flightinfo)

print(flightarr)
```

Comment: Not sure why, you are using the for loop to the adult, children and infants.

Comment: I use "For loop" for selecting the exact number what i need. what's else i can use?

Comment: I used your code but it is not working correctly.It's couldn't locate the xpath. here's the error  " selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id="availabilityTable0"]/tbody/tr/td[3]"} "